# AngularJs removes field focus on click only when there are field labels

Tags: angularjs, field, label

When I add a label to a field in any form within my AngularJS app, it results in a behavior where clicking a field assigns focus to the field above, thus making it impossible to select a field.

The quick fix it to not use labels and just a different tag to replace labels, but it seems like an odd bug not being able to use labels for fields. Anyone else experience this lately?

Here is an Angular fiddle for solving this Angular riddle:

http://bit.ly/154zU1H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up your close tags on the labels:

http://jsfiddle.net/ysQPt/

```
    <label>Label 1<label>

    <label>Label 1</label>
```

Comment: I think I need new glasses. Thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: It's always hard moving to a new framework... I had a couple of points on my first big project with angular that I was convinced there was a serious bug in the library only to realize I was doing something silly.